# Alimentar hidden field por click na coluna de uma tabela

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-5

Esse é meu jQuery que monta o HTML na minha cshtml.

```
$(data.resultado).each(function () {
                str += '<tbody>';
                    str += '<tr>';
                        str += '<td>';
                        str += '<label style="font-size:10px"><a href="#">' + data.resultado[cont].CNPJ + '</a></label>';
                        str += '</td>';
                        str += '<td>';
                        str += '<label style="font-size:10px"><a href="#">' + data.resultado[cont].RazaoSocial + '</a></label>';
                        str += '</td>';
                    str += '</tr>';
                str += '</tbody>';

                cont++;
            });
```

Como eu faço que ao clicar numa coluna (CNPJ ou RazaSocial), ele alimente um ou outro hidden field equivalente a coluna.

Então, coloquei o código passado pra mim e não vem nenhum alert quando eu clico na td correspondente. tblGrid é o nome da minha tabela. Fiz assim e nada no alert

```
$('#tblGrid').on('click', 'td', function (e) {
    var ancora = $(this).find('label a');
    var valor = ancora.text();

    alert(valor);

    // e agora use o valor como quiser
});
```

Comment: Clicar na coluna ou numa célula? O que você quer como valor do campo hidden?

Comment: Por favor evite ir metamorfoseando a pergunta conforme vai tentando as respostas. Neste caso eu suponho que a própria `#tblGrid` esteja sendo inserida dinamicamente, não? Tente `$(document).on(...` para confirmar se é esse o problema.

Comment: É o seguinte, complementar a pergunta *original* com mais informações é altamente desejável. Alterar a pergunta com o andamento da sua solução conforme vai tentando as sugestões das respostas não é desejável, pois a pergunta vira outra. Neste caso, você poderia comentar abaixo da minha resposta com algo assim: "testei esse código usando `#tblGrid` como seletor e um alert dentro com o valor, mas não aparece o alert".

Comment: Ué, vi que você aceitou minha resposta. Funcionou agora?

Answer (score 3):

Como você está injetando esse HTML no documento, é mais seguro usar delegação (substitua o seletor que usei abaixo por algo que selecione a tabela, ou o ancestral mais próximo dela que já exista no momento em que esse código vai rodar):

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function(e) {
    var ancora = $(this).find('label a');
    var valor = ancora.text();

    // e agora use o valor como quiser
});
```

Comment: Não funcionou. Creio que eu cliquei de forma errada, ou seja, pode ser que eu tenha marcado outra resposta em outro post e acabei me enganado e cliquei aqui, mas não resolveu não.